# How to add a class name to a specific selector

Tags: jquery

Considering the following html:

```
<div class="box">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="publication#all">ALL</a></li>
        <li><a href="publication#country">COUNTRY</a></li>
        <li><a href="publication#date">DATE</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab_all">...</div>

    <div id="tab_country">...</div>
    <div id="tab_date">...</div>
</div>
```

From a specific element, i want to add a class to the anchor **a** with an href of "publication#country"

This is what i've done so far with no success.

```
$("#tab_date").siblings("ul.tabs").find('li a[href=publication#country').addClass("current");
```

Comment: How to debug this kind of trouble: Take your whole selector query, put it into console and hit enter. If you get an empty array/object, your selector is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the second option is for leeches and lazy people.

Comment: Sure, nothing wrong with your question (I upvoted it!) - debugging trick just to help you.

Comment: change $("#tab_date").siblings("ul.tabs").find('li a[href=publication#country') to                                       $("#tab_date").siblings("ul.tabs").find("li a[href='publication#country']")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the closing bracket. Try this:

```
$("#tab_date").siblings("ul.tabs").find("li a[href='publication#country']").addClass("current");
```

*Note:* I originally thought the attribute selector value needed to be quoted (so I normally write it as above), however according to Rhumborl, and confirmed by Scott and myself, it does appear to work without the quoting. However it would be safer to get in the habit of including the quotes in case you encounter an unusual situation where omitting the quotes would cause issues.

Comment: It does also work without quoting it, but probably safer to anyway

Comment: @Rhumborl Ah yes, you're right. I just double checked, and it does indeed work without quoting.

Comment: @Marco No problem (don't forget to accept when you can). Definitely heed Dan's advice, it'll save you a ton of time next time you encounter an issue with jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 3):

You can select it via:

```
$("#tab_date").siblings("ul.tabs").find("li a[href=publication#country]");
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfx0c93t/6/

Comment: If he has the same pattern under a different section, it won't work.

Comment: True but he didn't specify all the other cases.  I see your point however and updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't notice, you noticed the missing `]`. +1 ood spotting